# React Native Issue - Initialize state by calling another method from constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have small React Native Component in which I try to initialize state by reading values from local storage **(AsyncStorage)**. But when I call the outside method from constructor I get ***undefined*** as state value.

Here is part of my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       languageChecked: I18n.locale, 
       anonymityChecked: this.pickLocalKey('anonymity', true), 
       locationChecked: this.pickLocalKey('location', false),  
       notificationChecked: this.pickLocalKey('notification', false),
       statisticsChecked: this.pickLocalKey('statistics', false),
    };
    console.log("STATE: " + this.state.anonymityChecked); // UNDEFINED
}

pickLocalKey(key, defaultValue) {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then((value) => {
    const item = (value !== null && value !== undefined) ? value : defaultValue;
    console.log(item);
    return item;
  });
}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with the code that you pasted in your question.

Firstly the `constructor` is synchronous and you trying to perform asynchronous tasks inside it. This is not a good idea.

If you need to load values from `AsyncStorage` and store them in `state` you should do it in the `componentDidMount`

So set initial values in the constructor, adding an additional value `loaded: false`. This will become important later on.

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    languageChecked: I18n.locale,
    anonymityChecked: true,
    locationChecked: false,
    notificationChecked: false,
    statisticsChecked: false,
    loaded: false // <- add this additional value
  };
}
```

Currently your `pickLocalKey` function isn't actually returning anything. The return value is trapped inside a promise. Luckily we can convert the function to use `async/await`. So it should look something like this:

```
pickLocalKey = async (key, defaultValue) => {
  try {
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    const item = (value !== null && value !== undefined) ? value : defaultValue;
    return item === 'true'; // this will make sure we get a Boolean back as long as you store strings 'true' and 'false' for your Booleans
  } catch (error) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```

Note that `await` can throw so it is always best to wrap it in a `try/catch`.

Then in your `componentDidMount` you should make the calls to retrieve the values from `AsyncStorage`

```
async componentDidMount () {
  // these won't throw as we are catching the error before it gets here
  let anonymityChecked = await this.pickLocalKey('anonymity', true);
  let locationChecked = await this.pickLocalKey('location', false);
  let notificationChecked = await this.pickLocalKey('notification', false);
  let statisticsChecked = await this.pickLocalKey('statistics', false);
  // set all items in state in one go as multiple calls to setState are not good
  this.setState({
    anonymityChecked,
    locationChecked,
    notificationChecked,
    statisticsChecked,
    loaded: true . // <- we set loaded to true
  }, () => console.log(this.state)); // this is how you check state after it has been set
}
```

Then in your `render` you should now use the fact that `loaded` is now true to render the correct view:

```
render () {
  if (this.state.loaded) {
    return (
      this is the view that you actually want to show
    )
  } else {
    return (
      this is the view that you will show when everything is loading
    )
  }
}
```

Here are some articles that are worth reading:

- https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8
- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0
- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296
- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6

Comment: I'm getting an error [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String]

Comment: You can only store strings in AsyncStorage. You should store your `true` values as `'true'` and your `false` values as `'false'`

Comment: That's make sense.

Comment: now is working fine! Thank you for this great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
pickLocalKey(key, defaultValue) {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then((value) => {
    const item = (value !== null && value !== undefined) ? value : defaultValue;
    console.log(item);
    return item;
  });
}
```

with

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pickLocalKey('anonymity', true, 'anonymityChecked');
    this.pickLocalKey('location', false, 'locationChecked');
    this.pickLocalKey('notification', false, 'notificationChecked');
    this.pickLocalKey('statistics', false, 'statisticsChecked')
    this.state = {
    };
}

pickLocalKey = (key, defaultValue, stateKey) => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then((value) => {
    const item = (value !== null && value !== undefined) ? value : defaultValue;
    console.log(item);
    this.setState({
     [stateKey]: item
    });

  });
}

render() {
 console.log(this.state);
}
```

EDIT:
So the issue is this a promise, now constructor run for once, not gonna wait for your promise to resolve. Also you cant or dont wanna make your constructor a promise. Once you get the data back, set the data not possible.
But you call the function then do setState. Then see the state in render, I hope you will see the right state.

Comment: now I get [object Object] instead of boolean value from local storage. How to solve that?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(value);` and show me what you are getting? Chances are value is a object. If you are just expecting a bool, you might wanna just pass based on the value.

Comment: Yes... console.log(this.state.anonymityChecked) is logging [object Object]. Before that was undefined.

Comment: I meant, `pickLocalKey =  async (key, defaultValue) => {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
console.log(value);
`

Comment: for first item: true, for second: false, third: false, fourth: false